# Bootstrap Container class not making elements center of the page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I written a simple following html code

```
<div class="container">
   <p>-----------Bootstrap Simple Test----------------</p>
</div>
```

It's looking exactly what I expected in mobile view. But in Desktop view it looks like there is more space on the right side. and It's not centered.

Attaching screenshot[image: More space on right side]

How can I make it look centered in Bootstrap ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `text-center` class like this:

`<p class="text-center">-----------Bootstrap Simple Test----------------</p>`

[Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-emphasis)

Comment: Thanks, But why we need to use container if we choose to use text-center ?

Comment: In your specific example you wouldn't need the container